# What will the error code when we create resources in resource group more than its limit

Tags: azure

I am writing an program where we create resources in resource group under a subscription using azure management API's.
If i exhaust the limit of number of resources created in resource group then what will be the response and error code in this case?

Answer (score 0):

During deployment, you receive an error stating that the current deployment will exceed the quota of 800 deployments.

Each resource group is limited to 800 deployments in its deployment history. This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-quota-exceeded) describes the error you receive when a deployment fails because it would exceed the allowed 800 deployments.